# Phpunit debug returns /-edit , but I am using '_edit'

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

Why do I have this as response ?

```
########## DEBUG ##########
'/companies/-edit/5'
###########################
```

from this code ?

```
debug(Router::url(['controller' => 'Companies', 'action' => '_edit', $entity->id]));
```

Pay attention to 'underline' iun the debugger and to a line as a response ?

Comment: Action names like this are invalid. Please use what the router expects, valid "camelBacked" method which then via Inflector and Route would become e.g. "dashed-one" for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CakePHP 3 you should be using the camelBacked naming convention for your controller actions. Prepending a controller method with an underscore `_` should be reserved for protected methods.

The CakePHP router will convert a camelBacked method to an user friendly dashed string. For example, the action `myBookings` would become `my-bookings` in the URL. CakePHP will also convert `_` to `-`, this is to allow backwards compatibility with old CakePHP 2 actions which were snake case.

Make sure you familiarise yourself with the [CakePHP naming conventions for Controllers](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#url-considerations-for-controller-names).